# betweennes centrality python

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello im new with python and i want to write a code to calculate the betweennes centrality for a graph .
i found brandes algorithm code on https://github.com/coreyabshire/tron/blob/master/brandes.py , but i dont understand it, specially what is V, and A, help please.
here is the code:

```
from collections import deque
def brandes(V, A):
"Compute betweenness centrality in an unweighted graph."
# Brandes algorithm
# see http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~rb4/resources/Brandes.pdf
C = dict((v,0) for v in V)
for s in V:
    S = []
    P = dict((w,[]) for w in V)
    g = dict((t, 0) for t in V); g[s] = 1
    d = dict((t,-1) for t in V); d[s] = 0
    Q = deque([])
    Q.append(s)
    while Q:
        v = Q.popleft()
        S.append(v)
        for w in A[v]:
            if d[w] < 0:
                Q.append(w)
                d[w] = d[v] + 1
            if d[w] == d[v] + 1:
                g[w] = g[w] + g[v]
                P[w].append(v)
    e = dict((v, 0) for v in V)
    while S:
        w = S.pop()
        for v in P[w]:
            e[v] = e[v] + (g[v]/g[w]) * (1 + e[w])
            if w != s:
                C[w] = C[w] + e[w]
return C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the paper [A Faster Algorithm for Betweenness Centrality](http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/publications/b-fabc-01.pdf) cited by the comments of the code, it appears as if `V` is the set of vertices and `A` is an `n` x `n` [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) for the given vertices.

Comment: `A` is an adjacency list, not an adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Here, V is a list of vertices and A is a dictionary representing the adjacency list for the graph in the form node : neighbor1, neighbor1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From implementing Corey Abshire's code myself, I found Unni's answer to be correct. 
For example: `V = ['A','B','C']` and 
`A = {'A' : ['B'], 'B' : ['A','C'], 'C' : ['B']}`

This represents the network: `A--B--C`. `brandes.py` outputs a dictionary `C = {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C':0}` since two shortest paths (A to C and C to A) pass through B.

Answer (score 0):

```
while S:
    w = S.pop()
    for v in P[w]:
        e[v] = e[v] + (g[v]/g[w]) * (1 + e[w])
        if w != s:
            C[w] = C[w] + e[w]
```

Please note the following section should not be within the for loop:
            if w != s:
                C[w] = C[w] + e[w]

I have checked the result using the python library networkx